# How to make activator dist ignore the package.json in the project root?

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

When running `activator dist`, `npm install` seems to executed automatically along with it in a step that appears in the logs as `[error] (web-assets:jseNpmNodeModules) Problems with NPM resolution. Aborting build.`
In my setup this should not happen as the CD server where the build is running is not equipped to resolve all dependencies through npm.
How can I disable this automatic behavior in sbt 0.13.8 with play plugin 2.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the JsEngine npmNodeModules step. [A Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/TJdFx1eXQZA) provided the following solution to disabled this step during build:
Setting `JsEngineKeys` to `Nil` in `build.sbt` as shown below solved the issue:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, BuildInfoPlugin)
  .settings(
    // Disable NPM node modules
    JsEngineKeys.npmNodeModules in Assets := Nil,
    JsEngineKeys.npmNodeModules in TestAssets := Nil
  )
```